# Building OpenCV 2.4.11 on Linux with `libopencv_ffmpeg.so`

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture

When downloading OpenCV sources, no matter whether it is for Windows or for Linux, the sources directory contains only the Windows already-compiled shared library `3rdparty/ffmpeg/opencv_ffmpeg.dll`, that is essential for the `VideoCapture` module to work on the Python portings for OpenCV.

In Linux, as this file is not provided, you'd expect it to be automatically built when you  build OpenCV, especially when in `CMakeCache.txt`, you can spot the line `WITH_FFMPEG:BOOL=ON`.

It is of course not built... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a great workaround - sharing with everybody.

Instead of using OpenCV's `VideoCapture`, I use the library `scikit-video`.

First, installing it (make sure to install a late enough version):

```
pip install sk-video
```

Then, reading videos in the following way:

```
import skvideo.io


cap = skvideo.io.vreader(input_video_filepath)
metadata = skvideo.io.ffprobe(input_video_filepath)
framerate = metadata['video']['@r_frame_rate']

for frame in cap:
    # Do whatever you want...
    # "cap" is a generator, the for loop will simply end when there are no more frames
    # "frame" is a NumPy array, just like in OpenCV's VideoCapture
```

Further docs and examples are available here:  http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html